# Codeception, mocking Guzzle

Tags: laravel, mocking, guzzle, codeception

Have some trouble with **mocking** in functional testing.

For mocking I use *Mockery* in *Laravel*, tests written on *Codeception*

Need to test sending verification message to user.

I tried mock Guzzle in few ways (Client, ClientInterface,  ResponceInterface), code seems like this:

```
$client = Mockery::mock(GuzzleHttp\Client::class);
$client->shouldReceive('get')->once();

$I->haveInstance(GuzzleHttp\Client::class, $client);
```

All tries receives:

> Method get() from Mockery_2_GuzzleHttp_Client should be called
>      exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Part of controller that i want to test:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = config('sms.url') . '/sys/send.php?login=' . config('sms.login') . '&psw=' . config('sms.password') . '&phones='
            . $user->phone . '&mes=' . urlencode($data['notification']) . '&charset=utf-8';
$client->get($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

> `haveInstance` method adds an instance binding to the Laravel service container.

Your controller code does not retrieve Guzzle Client from service container but creates a new instance. It is an untestable code.

You have to modify your controller code to use service container.

Comment: No, I don't use Laravel.